# CORS policy error - spotify api with Spring boot + React

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors, spotify

I am trying to write simple app with spotify api using Spring Boot and React.
In spring boot site i have a good working controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin()
public class SpotifyTopArtistClient {


    @GetMapping("/artist")
    public SpotifyArtist getTopArtist(OAuth2Authentication details){
        String jwt = ((OAuth2AuthenticationDetails)details.getDetails()).getTokenValue();

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("Authorization","Bearer "+jwt);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<SpotifyArtist> 
        exchange=restTemplate.exchange("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists? 
        time_range=medium_term&limit=1&offset=0", HttpMethod.GET,httpEntity,SpotifyArtist.class);


        return exchange.getBody();
    }

}
```

In class with the main method I have the bean:

```java
 @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "PATCH", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }
```

and my security class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/test").authenticated();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/artist").authenticated();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").authenticated();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login/*").authenticated();
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

When i'm testing endpoint http://localhost:8080/artist in browser and postman - it works as i expected.

On react side i have code:

```
  componentDidMount(){

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/artist')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data=>{
      console.log(data)
    })
  }
```

and when i'm trying to run this i see policy-CORS error:

**Access to fetch at 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=8c8db951b0614847b5faf36b300fcb07&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email%20user-top-read&state=vpHQLG' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/artist') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

Why addnotation **CrossOrigin** above **SpotifyTopArtistClient** class doesn't work this?
Maybe someone have a better experience with spotify api and could help me?
Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```java
@RestController
public class SpotifyTopArtistClient {
  (...)
}
```

Now update the `WebMvcConfigurer`:

```java
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
   return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
       @Override
       public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
           registry.addMapping("/**")
                   .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                   .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "PATCH", "OPTIONS")
                   .allowCredentials(true);
       }
   };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately, no changes

Comment: Are those endpoints authenticated? Do you have any other CORS configuration at global level?

Comment: yes, i have 'antMatchers' on  endpoint 'artist'.

Comment: Can you please add such Spring Security code to your answer?

Comment: Yes, i have add

Comment: Thanks, but avoid adding more stuff as answers when they are editions to the original question. I've edited my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Okay, sorry.  I change my code and update my post. Now i have other cors policy error

Comment: Now your issue is different and one that I guess you can't solve. Now it seems that `https://accounts.spotify.com/` is the domain blocking the call from `http://localhost:3000`. Not sure how to deal with that since Spotify API is not under our control.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. But there is so many apps using spotify api, and i don't understand why this spotify api blocking the call from fronted but accept from backend? Anyway thank for youy help

Comment: It is accepted from the Backend because CORS only applies to a web page in a browser. It is not applied when the call is from another Backend service. That is the reason why. If my answer was in some way helpful consider upvoting it or even accept it as correct so that others can benefit from it. Thanks!